# Can't configure properties-file in gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, discord, properties-file

So I'm trying to access a token key in my Kotlin code, but it won't let me import BuildConfig.

In my main() I have:

```
val client: DiscordClient = DiscordClientBuilder(BuildConfig.TOKEN_KEY).build()
```

`BuildConfig` is red in IntelliJ.

My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField("String", "TOKEN_KEY", apikeyProperties['TOKEN_KEY'])
}
```

Everywhere I look I see stackoverflow posts where they want defaultConfig to be in `android {}`, but I'm not making an Android app.

My token key is in a file called `apikey.properties` in root which has been added to `.gitignore`. 
Content of the file:

`TOKEN_KEY="token_value"`

Answer (score 2):

`BuildConfig` is a class generated by the Android Gradle plugin, hence it's not part of the Gradle's standard featrue set.

> At build time, Gradle generates the `BuildConfig` class so your app code can inspect information about the current build.

(From: [Share custom fields and resource values with your app's code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code))

Since you're not using Android plugin the class doesn't get generated and is red in IJ.

You have the following options:

- Deploy the properties file with your source code and read it accordingly during runtime
- Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938914/5006866) to the question [Generate a Java class using Gradle for Java plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20104323/5006866). It mentions the alternative [gradle-buildconfig-plugin](https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin) for non-Android projects.