# Gradle generate java source code from .tmpl file

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

Using `Ant` we generate some Java Code which mostly have some Runtime generated information.

for `ant task` we use below `VersionConstants.tmpl` file and it generates the

```
public class VersionConstants {

    /**
     * This class does not need to be instantiated.
     */
    private VersionConstants() { }


    public static final String VERSION = "@VERSION@";

    public static final String PATCH_LEVEL = "@PATCH_LEVEL@";

    public static final String REVISION = "@REVISION@";

    public static final String BUILDTIME = "@BUILDTIME@";

    public static final String BUILDHOST = "@BUILDHOST@";
}
```

using this we generate `VersionConstants.java` file. I saw this question [Generate a Java class using Gradle for Java plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20104323/1665592) but does `Gradle` support any native support for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are looking for a way to replace tokens in java source file by some values; there are plenty of gradle plugins that can do so, here's one of the examples:
https://github.com/HexoMod-tools/gradle.replace.token.preprocessor.plugin; you may try to search directly in gradle plugins registry, e.g. https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=replace

Comment: Thanks @alexander-makarov . your suggestion actually helped me to understand my requirements clearly and I'm able to solve the issue

Comment: @SwapnilKotwal no worries at all, could you please accept my answer then?

Answer (score 2):

I even avoided third party plugins and achieved it as below

```
task generateSources(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/replaceme/VersionConstants.java'
    into "$buildDir/generated-src"
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        "VERSION" : '1.0.0', 
        "PATCH_LEVEL" : '0.5',
        ...
    ])
}
```